# Update an entire row in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I'm new to MySQL and I want to update an entire row in MySQL with a new array, so far all the examples of the Update query involves specifying the column name and a new value for that column, like this:

```
"UPDATE tablename SET columnname = '".$new_value."' WHERE columnname = '".$value."'";
```

How can I update an entire record with the update query or should I use the replace query?

Any advice will be appreciated.

Edit: Is there a query which doesn't require to specify all the column names and new column values?

Basically I want to have a query that looks something like this:

*Update entirerow with thisarray where primarykeycolumn='thisvalue'*

Comment: Thanks for all your answers, I just wish their was a shorter query /*cries*/

Answer (score 27, accepted):

To do that you need to

1. Enumerate all the values
2. Know the primary key column and value

So the final query would look like

```
UPDATE tablename
   SET col1 = 'val1', col2 = 'val2' ...
 WHERE id = id_value
```

There is no any magic command for updating the "whole row" in sql other than I shown above. And `REPLACE` is definitely not what you need here.

Comment: Ok thanks, then I guess I should stop being lazy and  start typing those columns.

Comment: Title specifically said `MySQL`. Unless you're trying to convert him to Postgres it doesn't really apply to mention it :)

Comment: @AlienWebguy: Not trying to convert anyone. MySQL allows this syntax in `WHERE` clause: `WHERE (a,b) = (2,3)` is valid in MySQL (and SQL in general). But it hasn't been implemented yet in the `SET` clause.

Comment: @ypercube are you the same person as zerkms? I know the syntax :)

Comment: @ypercube why would you add a code snippet to someone else's answer? Seems strange and inappropriate.

Comment: @AlienWebguy: We can discuss that on meta if it is strange or inappropriate. See a related discussion: [When is it appropriate to edit another user's answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80513/when-is-it-appropriate-to-edit-another-users-answer)

Comment: For other rookies that come along and find this, the second code block ONLY WORKS IN POSTGRES. I know it says that, but I missed it and spent a while trying to figure out why it wouldn't work. :)

Answer (score 8):

It depends if you want to keep the ID or not, assuming the ID is `autoincrement`.

`REPLACE INTO mytable VALUES( new array ) ....` will update the ID as well, since it really just emulates a `DELETE` and `INSERT`.

If you want to keep the ID, use an `UPDATE mytable SET foo='bar', baz='bat' WHERE id=12`

As an FYI, `REPLACE` is generally convenient for mapping tables where the unique field or composite primary key isn't an autoincrement.

Comment: And it's also not good to use `REPLACE` when there are Foreign Keys pointing to this table (especially with `ON DELETE CASCADE` action defined).

Comment: Yes unfortunately the id is autoincrement and I need to keep those

Answer (score 4):

That is the correct way.

```
UPDATE TABLENAME SET COLUMNAME = VALUE, COLUMN2NAME = VALUE, ETC WHERE CONDITION
```

Answer (score 3):

You can certainly do it all in one query.  You just add more this = that clauses separated by commas:

```
"UPDATE tablename 
SET column1name = '".$new_value1."', 
    column2name = '".$new_value2."', 
    column3name = '".$new_value3."' 
WHERE columnname = '".$value."'"
```

Answer (score -2):

Yes there is a similar way...

```
$updateSQL = sprintf("UPDATE hotel <br>SET hotel_name=%s, contact_person_1=%s <br>WHERE hotel_id=%s",<br>
                       $_POST['hotel_name'],<br>
                       $_POST['contact_person_1'],<br>
                       $_POST['hotel_id']);

mysql_select_db($database_hotelbookingryan, $hotelbookingryan);
$Result1 = mysql_query($updateSQL, $hotelbookingryan) or die(mysql_error());
```